# Java - Não pôde encontrar classe principal

Tags: java, compilação

O código abaixo não compila:

```
package app1;

public class main{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

A seguinte mensagem aparece no terminal:

> Error: Could not find or load main class main

o arquivo `main.java` está salvo na pasta `app1`. Estou compilando pelo terminal no Manjaro.

Não entendo, quando eu compilo na IDE (seja NetBeans ou Eclipse) o código roda, mas pelo terminal dá errado. Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Linha de comando para rodar que você está testando?

Comment: javac main.java [enter]
java main [enter]

Comment: Do jeito que você está rodando, o Java esperaria que estivesse sem pacote na classe. Você disse que ela estava dentro da pasta `app1`, certo? Tente `java -classpath ../ main`. O `-classpath` é ensinando ao Java qual o caminho que ele deve ir atrás das classes. Como você está dentro da pasta `app1` (você disse acima), então a raiz está acima disso, logo a raiz está em `..`

Answer (score 2):

O erro está nessa chamada: `java main`

Você deve utilizar o nome completo da classe que nesse caso é: app1.main.
Porém, ainda assim não irá funcionar. O java tentará entrar em um pacote app1 para encontrar a classe. Contudo, você já está dentro do pacote. Para que a chamada funcione, você precisa adicionar o pacote pai do app1 no classpath do java. O classpath é uma espécie de lista de diretórios onde o java irá procurar as classes necessárias para executar o código.

Portanto, sua chamada deveria ser: `java -cp .. app1.main`

Para que o comando fique mais fácil você pode sair da pasta app1 e ir para a pasta pai dela. Dessa forma, você pode executar esse comando: `java app1.main`

Só esclarecendo algumas coisas. Seu código não dá erro de compilação. O que acontece é um erro de execução. O java não consegue encontrar a classe com o main porque você não está passando o nome correto e nem está informando onde encontrar a classe.

Dica: Nome de classes em java devem começar com letra maiúscula.

Comment: Valeu pela dica! Estou estudando C e Java ao mesmo tempo e termino que confundindo quando usar uma letra maiúscula ou quando não usar. Quanto ao classpath eu não sei como alterar. Darei uma pesquisada na internet e caso consiga resolver eu fecho o tópico.

Comment: Na verdade, você irá chamar o comando exatamente como eu coloquei aí que irá funcionar. Você está chamando o comando em que pasta?

Comment: Na pasta onde exatamente está o arqui ´.java´. /home/username/code/NomeArquivo.java

Comment: O correto seria você ter um pasta chamada app1 e dentro da pasta um arquivo chamado main.java. O nome da classe tem que ser igual ao nome do arquivo da classe. A classe precisa estar em um path que corresponde ao package que ela se encontra.

Comment: Verifiquei que se o nome da classe não corresponder ao nome do arquivo, dá erro de compilação. Então provavelmente o nome do seu arquivo já está correto. Tente mudar o nome da pasta code para app1 e depois execute um dos comandos descritos na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve garantir que a localização do seu .classarquivo adicione ao seu classpath. Então, se estiver na pasta atual, adicione-o .ao seu classpath. Observe que o separador do classpath do Windows é um ponto-ponto, ou seja,;

Comment: Não vou mentir, não entendi nada. Estou começando na linguagem Java agora. Não uso Windows, uso Manjaro Linux.